# Deleting item from double linked list

Tags: c, list, pointers

I'm trying to write code that will remove an element at a given position from a double linked list. However, my code is resulting in the element not being removed and instead being replaced with garbage data.

I tested the code on the list `4,5,11,12,6,9` and tried to remove the third element (11). The result was `4,5,767133(trash),12,6,9`.

Can anyone tell me what the problem with the following code is?

```
struct L2k{
    unsigned int count;
    struct el_L2k *head;
    struct el_L2k *tail;
};
struct L2k* removeFromPosition(struct L2k *L2k,int position)
{
    if(position > L2k->count || position < 1)
    {
        printf("No such position\n");
        return L2k;
    }

    int i;
    struct el_L2k *temp = L2k->head;

    for(i=1;i<position;i++)
        temp=temp->next;

    printf("Deleting %d",temp->data);

    if(temp->prev!=NULL)
        temp->prev->next=temp->next;
    else
        L2k->head=temp->next;

    if(temp->next!=NULL)
        temp->next->prev=temp->prev;
    else
        L2k->tail=temp->prev;

    L2k->count--;
    free(temp);
    return L2k;
};
```

Comment: Haven't done C in years and not following your code too well (use braces! even with single lines ... it'll save your butt in the future).  Anyway, the general concept:  If you've got 3 items in the list and you want to get rid of the second, set #1's down pointer to #3.  Set #3s up pointer to #1.  Free the memory for #2

Comment: @mortsahl I think if-else part of my code does exactly what you said

Comment: Your code isn't clear (to me) and you need to use intention revealing variable names.  Anyway, from my previous 3 items scenario, one->next = two->next; three->prev = two->prev.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: a) The garbage is probably freed `temp` bit of memory   
b) Looks like the code would work fine   
These two things mean its likely the display code isn't really traversing the list (but displaying an old array or something)

Comment: what is _el_L2k_? and what is _prev_ and _next_?

Comment: @TuBui Guess what prev and next can mean. Maybe previous and next element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something is wrong with your list BEFORE you try to delete an element.

Show us a well-formed list before the delete.  Show us the code that makes the list.  Show us the declaration of struct el_L2k.

Comment: This is really a comment rather than an answer...

Comment: @noelicus: I agree, but I wasn't allowed to enter a comment since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: You were right, there was an issue with list before deleting.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your signature `void removeFromPosition(struct L2k **, int )`.

When you are passing the first argument in your code, your head is duplicated as a local variable(with local scope) to your function. When the function returns, the scope ends and the variables are dumped by default. This is why you are getting a garbage for a value and your pointers are intact. Use a pointer to your head as the first argument, and modify the code accordingly. You will get a proper deletion.

Good Luck!